# Vue JS 3: How to pass data from one component to another other?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm trying to share data stored in a variable `favorite_count` within the Favorites component in `Favorites.vue` file. I want to share that data with the App Component in the `App.vue` file but I'm not able to. I would want that if I change the value of `favorite_count` in the Favorites component, it changes in the App Component. Done quite some research on the web but no success yet. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

`Favorites.vue file`

```
<template>
    <div class="row m-5">
        <h3 class="col-8">Your Favorites</h3>
        <div class="col-4">
            <p class="pull-right m-1">Picks 
            <span >{{ favorite_count }}</span>  / 5</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'favorites',
    data() {
        return {
            favorite_count: 5,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        changeFavoriteCount() { 
            this.favorite_count = this.favorite_count + 2;
        },
        emitToParent (event) {
          this.$emit('childToParent', this.favorite_count)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

`App.vue` file

```
<template>
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav"> 
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <router-link to="/favorites" class="btn btn-info">
                      Favorites ( {{ favorite_count }} )
                    </router-link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> 
</template>
<script> 
import Favorites from './components/Favorites.vue'
 
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Favorites
  },
  data () {
    return { 
      favorite_count: 0, 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you should use vuex

Comment: see example https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-tree-w0lq8 it saves polluting everything with vars

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are going to use `<router-view>` later in your application, I would suggest [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68217600/16315484)

If you were going to include `Favorites` inside `<template>` in `App.vue`, you can use [**props**](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#prop-types):

**1.** Declare your 'shared' variable in the parent component (App.vue)

```
data () {
  return { 
    favorite_count: 0, 
  }
},
```

**2.** Define props in your child component (Favorites.vue)

```
export default {
  props: { favorite_count: Number },
  ...
}
```

**3.** Pass `favorite_count` as prop to `Favorites`

```
<template>
  ...
    <Favorites :favorite_count="favorite_count" ... />
</template>
```

If you will need to update `favorite_count` - emit an event to parent component. More about it in [Vue docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#custom-events)

**Edit:** Just to clarify: If you are going to update `favorite_count` from **Favorites.vue**, you need to emit an event to **App.vue** to avoid mutating props.

That also means you need to move your `changeFavoriteCount()` function to **App.vue** and apply a listener to your child component which will call this function:

```
// App.vue
<template>
  ...
    <Favorites 
       @your-update-event="changeFavoriteCount" 
       :favorite_count="favorite_count" ...
    />
</template>

...

changeFavoriteCount(newVal) { 
    this.favorite_count = newVal;
},
```

Answer (score 2):

change your `Favourite.vue` file like this

```
<template>
  <div class="row m-5">
    <h3 class="col-8">Your Favorites</h3>
    <div class="col-4">
      <p class="pull-right m-1">
        Picks <span>{{ favorite_count }}</span> / 5

        <button @click="changeFavoriteCount">Click me to change favorite_count</button>
      </p>
    </div>
    <hr />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "favorites",
  data() {
    return {
      favorite_count: 5,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeFavoriteCount() {
      this.favorite_count = this.favorite_count + 2;
      this.emitToParent();
    },
    emitToParent() {
      this.$emit("childToParent", this.favorite_count);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

and the App.vue file like this

```
<template>
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav"> 
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <router-link to="/favorites" class="btn btn-info">
                      
                      <Favorites @childToParent="updateFavorite" />
                      Favorites ( {{ favorite_count }} )
                    </router-link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> 
</template>
<script> 
import Favorites from './components/Favorites.vue'
 
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Favorites
  },
  data () {
    return { 
      favorite_count: 0, 
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateFavorite(data) {
      this.favorite_count = data;
    },
  },
}
</script>
```